# Android Java, скриншот всего экрана

Tags: java, android, экран, screenshots

Здравствуйте, делаю проект - нужно сделать скриншот экрана, при этом не скриншот View, как везде в интернете написано, а скриншот именно всего экрана. При этом нужно чтобы приложение работало в фоновом режиме, то есть я вышел из него, лажу например где-то в галереи, а приложение делает скриншот, скажем, раз в минуту. Как это реализовать? Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292738/take-screenshot-of-current-showing-screen-not-the-current-activity/40293009#40293009

Comment: в комментарии выше дана ссылка на ответ, если вы хотите чтобы скрины делались автоматически с заданным интервалом то к изложенному там еще прикрутите JobScheduler

Answer (score 0):

Через командную строку выполнять команду: `screencap -p /sdcard/img.png`.

Например так:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p /sdcard/img.png");
```